# How to create an html list that give a result with the UL Level numbers as the list value

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to make an HTML list that looks like the following with CSS

### **1.** List item

**2.** List item

**3.** List item

**3.** List item

**3.** List item

**4.** List item

**4.** List item

**2.** List item

**2.** List item

### **1.** List item

### **1.** List item

**2.** List item

### **1.** List item

I had tried the following, I don't need the current list item numberings

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
  color: red;
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>LIST ITEM</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>LIST ITEM</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>LIST ITEM</li>
                    <li>LIST ITEM</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>LIST ITEM</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>LIST ITEM</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>LIST ITEM</li>
            <li>LIST ITEM</li>
            <li>LIST ITEM</li>
            <li>LIST ITEM</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>LIST ITEM</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You does not need counter here as you are not increasing or decreasing your counter value on same level...use `:before` pseudo class for each level instead

***Stack Snippet***

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "1. Link ";
  color: red;
}

ul li li:before {
  content: "2. Link ";
}

ul li li li:before {
  content: "3. Link ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>LIST ITEM</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>LIST ITEM</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>LIST ITEM</li>
          <li>LIST ITEM</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>LIST ITEM</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>LIST ITEM</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>LIST ITEM</li>
      <li>LIST ITEM</li>
      <li>LIST ITEM</li>
      <li>LIST ITEM</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>LIST ITEM</li>
</ul>
```

***Updated:*** If you want a dynamic solution use `parents()` jQuery to calculate the level of each `li`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$("li").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("data-level", $(this).parents("ul").length)
})
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font: 13px Verdana;
  margin-top: -15px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

ul li:before {
  content: attr(data-level) ". ";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>LIST ITEM</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>LIST ITEM</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>LIST ITEM</li>
          <li>LIST ITEM</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>LIST ITEM</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>LIST ITEM</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>LIST ITEM</li>
      <li>LIST ITEM</li>
      <li>LIST ITEM</li>
      <li>LIST ITEM</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>LIST ITEM</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But Its hard coded, I needs to changing the values dynamically

Comment: @asp why do you want to change it dynamically..? I don't see any benefit here to change it dynamically...if you want, you have to write a counter for every level and then increment it on `:before` or another way is using `jQuery` but it will produce the same result with extra code...

Comment: The list may have __n__ number of UL inside each, it is not possible to manage with __n__ number of list

Comment: @asp I added a second solution using `parent()` jQuery...have a look...

Comment: hmm.. I also found that no other way to doing this only with CSS and I had done the same with JQuery, Anyway I'm appretiating you to taking effort on fixing the problem and accepting your answer...

Answer (score 0):

I almost said "you can't do that with CSS"... but turns out you can.

With horrendously specific child selectors, you can :p

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}

ul li:before {
  content:"1. ";
}

ul > ul li:before{
  content:"2. ";
}

ul > ul > ul li:before{
  content:"3. ";
}

ul > ul > ul > ul li:before{
  content:"4. ";
}

/* and so on, and so forth :p */
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>LIST ITEM</li>
    <ul>
        <li>LIST ITEM</li>
        <ul>
            <li>LIST ITEM</li>
            <li>LIST ITEM</li>
        </ul>
        <li>LIST ITEM</li>
    </ul>
    <li>LIST ITEM</li>
    <ul>
        <li>LIST ITEM</li>
        <li>LIST ITEM</li>
        <li>LIST ITEM</li>
        <li>LIST ITEM</li>
        <ul>
          <li>LIST ITEM</li>
          <ul>
                <li>LIST ITEM</li>
          </ul>
       </ul>
    </ul>
    <li>LIST ITEM</li>
</ul>
```

c'mon, don't tell me that's not the most ingenious and ridiculous line of CSS you've seen today :)